# Can't get file to save to DB using Carrierwave_direct

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I wanted to try out Carrierwave_direct with my app so I decided to follow the Railscast episode. http://railscasts.com/episodes/383-uploading-to-amazon-s3

I am using Carrierwave for a variety of uploads including Images, Videos, and Songs. Right now though, I'm only testing the video to see how I like it. Right now, the video's are getting uploaded to my Amazon bucket, but the file (string) isn't getting saved to my database and not rendering on the page. Here is where I am right now...

```
Rails v 4.0.1
Ruby v 2.1.1
```

Video Uploader

```
class VideoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWaveDirect::Uploader

  # I haven't added any resizing or anything yet
end
```

Video Model (video.rb)

```
mount_uploader :video, VideoUploader # In the database, the column is video:string
...
...
```

Page to upload file, before being redirected to form

```
def home
  @uploader = Video.new.video
  @uploader.success_action_redirect = new_video_url
end
```

Videos controller

```
def new
  @video = Video.new(key: params[:key])
end

def create
  @video = current_user.videos.create(video_params)
  ...
end

private

  def video_params
    params.require(:video).permit(:type, :title, :description, :video)
  end
```

home.html.erb (where the video upload is BEFORE it successfully redirects you to the rest of the form)

```
<%= direct_upload_form_for @uploader do |f| %>
  <p><%= f.file_field :video %></p>
  <p><%= f.submit "Upload Video" %></p>
<% end %>
```

videos/_form.html.erb (the rest of the video form)

```
<%= form_for(@video, html: { :class => "full-form form-vertical" }) do |f| %>
  <fieldset>

   <%= render "shared/error_messages", object: f.object %>

   <%= f.hidden_field :key %>

   <div class="form-group">
     <%= f.label :title %>
     <%= f.text_field :title, :class => "form-control" %>
   </div>

   <%= f.submit %>
 </fieldset>
<% end %>
```

My amazon is configured properly, so I won't provide my carrierwave.rb initializer file.

So to reiterate, what's happening is on the first page, I will upload the video which will redirect me to the form. If I inspect the form, I can see that the `:key` has the proper value in it. But, if I put a presence validator on the model, the form won't submit because the video will be blank. And if there is no validation, the form will submit, amazon will upload it to my bucket, but (1) the video file name/string won't be stored in my db and (2) it won't render on the page, because it's empty.

Thanks for taking a look. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

#video_params needs to permit :key, in your video controller.

```
private

  def video_params
    params.require(:video).permit(:type, :title, :description, :video, :key)
  end
```

You brought the :key all the way down, set it in #new, kept it with the hidden_field, and then lost it on the strong params.

The :key needs to get back to the VideoUploader object which is mounted under Video as :video, this is what allows your Video class to accept the :key attribute.

Video Model (video.rb)

```
mount_uploader :video, VideoUploader # In the database, the column is video:string
...
```